# Can open formulas of first-order logic imply other open formulas?

Tags: first-order-logic

Consider the open formula $x=0$. Does it imply the open formula $(x=0 \vee x=1)$? I know the definition of what it means for a closed sentence to imply another closed sentence relative to a first-order theory $T$. I am now wondering what it means for an open formula to imply another open formula. The reason I am asking this is because I got into a dispute with a math professor. He says that, strictly speaking, something like $x=0$ does not imply $(x=0 \vee x=1)$, because there is a free variable present. He does agree that the closed sentence $(\forall x)(x=0 \rightarrow (x=0 \vee x=1))$ is a true sentence. I argued that the open formula $(x=0 \rightarrow (x=0 \vee x=1))$ is true as well, because I am working in a formulation of first-order logic that allows open formulas as well-formed formulas. So, my question is, can open formulas imply other open formulas, and if so, what is the formal definition of an open formula implying another open formula? And also, are there textbooks on first-order logic that allow open formulas as well-formed formulas?

Comment: Well, for any formulas $\varphi,\psi$ you can consider the formula $\varphi\to\psi$ and check if it(s closure) is a theorem in $T$ or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are talking about implication *in the metalanguage* here, that is, not of implication in the internal syntax of first-order logic:

$\varphi_1$ implies $\varphi_2$ if every structure $\mathcal{A}$ that is a model of $\varphi_1$ is also a model of $\varphi_2$.

This can be defined for *any* first-order formulae irrespective of whether they are closed or not.

Clearly, if $\mathcal{A}$ is a model of the open formula $x = 0$, then we also (by the semantics of disjunction) have that $\mathcal{A}$ is a model of the open formula $(x = 0 \vee x =1)$.